# How to convert ruby hash_sym from hash arrow to hash colon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, symbols

In Rails: I like to convert

my_arrow_hash = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}

to

My_colon_hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

Comment: The two are equivalent. `{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} == {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} #=> true`

Comment: What do you mean you want to convert them? Are you saying that the code you have written uses hashrockets and you want to change it to symbolized keys? Or are you saying your code appears to output hashrockets and you want to change how it renders when you view it?

Comment: One of the method in rails that I need to use required input in that format. Can you answer this?

Comment: In Ruby those are equivalent and the differences are irrelevant. Is this being passed in as a string? I can't think of a Rails method that would have such a peculiar interface, but maybe you can show what you're trying to do and how this could be a problem.

Comment: I know it’s the same value. But when try with Rails 6,7 update_all the bulk update the hash with arrow won’t work for me, all example use hash: value. So will just follow but need to convert all big array of hash. I wish it’s my mistake.

Comment: @PKul can you update your question with an example of one hash working and the other one not?

Comment: After carefully go through each step, there are some that turn my array of hash (of string) to symbol as sample in document (which not work in my case). It's need array of hash with key as string to be input for insert_all. Now it work, it has nothing to do with conversion I asked for/ Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are identical. They both declare a hash with keys that are ruby symbols `:a`, `:b`, and `:c`.

The first declaration (`{:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}`) uses the traditional ruby syntax to declare the hash.

The second declaration (`{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`) uses a newer and shorter syntax that was introduced in Ruby 1.9 and can only be used when the keys are ruby symbols.